Android equivalent Flutter Hex to Int Conversion
I'm working on a Flutter project and wanted to write logic to convert Hex to Int. I was able to convert it, but wondering what is the Flutter equivalent of the following Android conversion code, especially, 'and 0x0007', 'and 0x0038', 'and 0x0380'
            var string1 = NumberUtil.convertHexToInt(stringArray.get(3)) and 0x0007
            var string2 = NumberUtil.convertHexToInt(stringArray.get(3)) and 0x0038
            string2 = string2 shr 3 (I know in flutter,it is string2 = string2 >> 3)
            var string3 = NumberUtil.convertHexToInt(stringArray.get(3)) and 0x0380
            string3 = string3 shr 7 (I know in flutter,it is string3 = string3 >> 7)


I'm not sure what NumberUtil is, but you can parse a String containing a hexadecimal representation of an integer with just int.parse/int.tryParse.  If you want to perform a bitwise AND on an int, use &).  For example: int.parse('0xABCD') & 0x0007

Does this answer your question? Convert an arbitrarily long hexadecimal string to a number in Dart?

@jamesdlin NumberUtil is a Utility method to convert Hex to Int. Your solution worked as expected. Thank you so much.
  var string1 = utilityhelper.convertHexStringToInt(eventsArray[3]) & 0x0007;
  var string2 = utilityhelper.convertHexStringToInt(eventsArray[3]) & 0x0038;
  string2 = string2 >> 3;
  var string3 = utilityhelper.convertHexStringToInt(eventsArray[3]) & 0x0380;
  string3 = string3 >> 7;

